# Create a map of spain with lakes

Tags: r, tmap

I have a shapefile of water from Spain and boundaries shapefile of Spain.

boundaries shapefile called boundaries
and water shapfile is called water

```
boundaries <- st_read("boundaries_spain.shp")
water <- st_read("water_spain.shp")
```

I changed the names of the shapefile. boundaries are the administrative areas and water is the inland water

Both shapefiles can be found here
https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

I used that code but seems not work to add lakes into a legend

```
 tm_shape(boundaries) +
  tm_borders("grey", lwd = 1.25) + tm_shape(water_shp) + tm_fill("blue", title.col="water bodies")
```

But it doesn't work that an output with a legend

the website seems to be the best solution I can find since I am not able to share my data

Comment: tmap is the package i am using

Comment: Perhaps adding one more line like this? `tm_add_legend('Lake',  type = "fill", col = "blue", border.col = "blue", title = "Lake")`

Comment: @jazzurro thank you very much, if you write as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, I leave my code here as a reference. Adding `tm_add_legend()` does the job you asked.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

spain <- st_read("ESP_adm2.shp")
water <- st_read("ESP_water_areas_dcw.shp")

tm_shape(spain) +
  tm_borders("grey", lwd = 1.25) +
  tm_shape(water) + 
  tm_fill("blue", title.col="water bodies") +
  tm_add_legend('Lake', 
                type = "fill",
                col = "blue",
                border.col = "blue",
                title = "Lake") -> g

tmap_save(g, "spain_water.png")
```

[image]